# How to get image url from Aws s3 and store it in mongodb using lambda function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need a URL location of an image from AWS s3 and store it in MongoDB with the lambda function. I know how to do this simple way using servers, attached code is working great, uploading the image and then getting the image url from the bucket and saving into mongodb.
but I want to do this same using lambda function. Please help me to code this in lambda function and guide me step by step ,I am totally new to this aws lambda

userController.js :

```js
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

const User = require("../models/userModel");

const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.S3_BUCKET_REGION,
});

const upload = (bucketName) =>
  multer({
    storage: multerS3({
      s3,
      bucket: bucketName,
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `image-${Date.now()}.jpeg`);
      },
    }),
  });

exports.setProfilePic = (req, res, next) => {
  const uploadSingle = upload("profile-picture-upload-youtube").single(
    "croppedImage"
  );

  uploadSingle(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err)
      return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err.message });

    await User.create({ photoUrl: req.file.location });

    res.status(200).json({ data: req.file.location });
  });
};
```

`

Comment: Hello I am not familiar with js but I can tell you logic. You can use API gateway and link your lambda with API. Now you can send image to your api and upload image to s3 bucket using aws-sdk and store image url to mongoldb. Hope it make sense . Thank you

Comment: yeah I did same thing above, but I cant code that as a lambda function, can u help me with it ,even python code will work for me

Comment: Sure but its really hard to explain all here. are you familiar with python?

Comment: yes I am familiar with python

Comment: I am sharing one blog where you can learn how to create api with lambda [link](https://dwdraju.medium.com/python-function-on-aws-lambda-with-api-gateway-endpoint-288eae7617cb). With the help of api you can send images to you lambda function and upload it to s3 and store s3 url to your mongoldb. Actually you can google all this like how to create post api using API gateway. You need to write your code inside lambda_handler function. That's all I can do here Hope you it will help.